# set kafka & zookeeper volume sizes using helm bitnami kafka charts

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, bitnami-kafka

I have setup helm chart values for bitnami kafka & zookeper values

```
kafka:
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    size: 50M
    mountPath: /bitnami/kafka
    storageClass: default
    existingClaim: ""
  zookeeper:
    volumePermissions:
      enabled: true
    persistence:
      enabled: true
      storageClass: default
      existingClaim: ""
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      size: 50M
      dataLogDir:
        size: 50M
        existingClaim: ""
```

It seems the pvc created for kafka is of size 16 gigs. Is there a way to setup very small disk size for testing purposes?

Comment: I suggest you ask this question in the bitnami charts github repo, or look at the source code of the charts if the size is hardcoded to 16G

Comment: Would be hard to answer this without taking a look at the charts. So as mentioned by @OneCricketeer once you get the variable for setting the pvc size, you can override that variable. And say you are not allowed to change values.yaml directly, since it's used by multiple sources etc, to override it, helm allows you to pass those values through cli as well using set flag or a file for override values, which can be passed in ```helm upgrade --install <service> -f values.yaml```

Answer (score 0):

once `storageClass: default` is changed to `storageClass: ""` or `storageClass: "-"` it starts to take the values supplied into account. Locally I could go as low as 50M, but on cluster I was able to go only as low as 1Gi.

I think it relates to the existing PV setup.

Answer (score -1):

According to the values.yaml of Bitnami Kafka Helm Chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml you don't need to define field "kafka". So, removing "kafka:" and adjusting idents accordingly should work:

```
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    size: 50M
    mountPath: /bitnami/kafka
    storageClass: default
    existingClaim: ""
  zookeeper:
    volumePermissions:
      enabled: true
    persistence:
      enabled: true
      storageClass: default
      existingClaim: ""
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      size: 50M
      dataLogDir:
        size: 50M
        existingClaim: ""
```